# Help me!! How do I create the background layer'?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography

[image: how do i create the white layer behind the word 'awfully'?]

how do i create the white layer behind the word 'awfully'?

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the text layer in the Layers Panel to open the Layer Style and select stroke.

Answer (score -3):

You would use the **Offset Path Tool**. Here is a useful tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rt15_OclsyI

**Edit**: I though this was an Illustrator question so the link above redirects you to an Illustrator tutorial.

I would then recommend this tutorial for Photoshop:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjGSkQXXv7o

However, you should be using Illustrator for this project because it is a better tool for the job.

Comment: The question is tagged Photoshop not Illustrator

Comment: Hi user37388, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: The question is about obtaining the design shown in the question's picture. That uses a technique called Path Offset. I initially thought it was an Illustrator question so I linked a Youtube tutorial that thoroughly explains how to get that type of design. Then I realized the question was about Photoshop so I linked another useful tutorial about how to obtain that effect in Photoshop. I then advised the use of Illustrator instead of Photoshop for it because it is a better fit. If you don't allow links to other tutorials, next time I will explain everything myself.